# Moodle users assigned to a course at sign up

Tags: moodle

I am new to Moodle, but I need to create a nasty custom feature for deployment.

When a user chooses to signup and create an account, they have to be placed in a group and only see their own version of the courses based on a job role they specify. There will be 3 different job roles and three different versions of the course.

I have added a custom field on signup to pick a job role, but what is the best way to go about doing this, or can Moodle support something like this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Cohorts - also called Audiences.
http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Cohorts

A cohort is a group of users or members. This can be created dynamically but using rules. So a rule can be created for a user's profile for example, to include them in a particular cohort.

Once the cohort is set up, you can automatically enrol members of a cohort onto a course.
http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Cohort_sync

So I would have 3 courses and 3 cohort groups.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle still does not support dynamic cohorts.

I think what "Russell England" is talking about is the totara moodle distribution (http://www.totaralms.com) only this supports a dynamic rule based cohort creation. I am building a plugin to support this may be sooner i will release this plugin